# AWS S3 Bucket Policy not working on mobile browsers

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-s3

my problem is the following:
I deployed a website on heroku and used "AWS S3 Bucket" for image hosting. I added a bucket policy so the images can only be loaded when called by referrer, which is my domain. It works for all desktop browsers but if I open the page with Safari or Chrome from my iPhone the images won't load.
My bucket Policy is the following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "diearch.images bucket Policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from diearch.herokuapp.com.",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::diearch-images/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://diearch.herokuapp.com/*",
                    "diearch.herokuapp.com*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root" //user changed 
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::diearch-images/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://diearch.herokuapp.com/*",
                    "diearch.herokuapp.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

My CORS is as folows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://diearch.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not whitelisting the http-adress. Safari and mobile browsers didn't send https.

Comment: What does this mean? How did you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where my website would work fine in Chrome on desktop, but on mobile, the root domain (the example.com) was not redirecting to S3 so the website was unavailable unless you enter the whole "example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" domain. To fix it, in my subdomain (the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) > Properties > Static website hosting, i changed protocol from HTTP to none and that fixed my issue.

This SO post helped me: [Solve the mystery: Why would AWS S3 website redirect not work with Chrome (and Safari) - but works with Edge and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584583/solve-the-mystery-why-would-aws-s3-website-redirect-not-work-with-chrome-and-s/66450286#66450286)