# Solve the mystery: Why would AWS S3 website redirect not work with Chrome (and Safari) - but works with Edge and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-ec2, mobile-safari

I am pretty mystified by this - so I thought I would put this up on Stack Overflow to see if someone smarter than me could solve this.

I set up a test website https://example.com on an AWS EC2 instance. I set up forwarding on AWS S3 bucket for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to forward to https://example.com. I also set up a forwarding record/routing policy for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on AWS' Route 53.

Now, I can get to the website going directly (https://example.com), but when I type in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I can only get there in Firefox and Edge. It times out with Chrome (and Safari on my iphone). Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I finally debugged this, and I figured I should share my wisdom after wasting HOURS researching rabbit holes.

I had port 80 turned off to prevent HTTP traffic. However, for some reason, Chrome overrides the AWS S3 redirect to take [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to https://example.com - and sends it to HTTP://example.com. I guess Safari does the same. I have NO idea why - but KEEP your Port 80 open!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and in my case it was the protocol under website hosting, mine was set to "https" and changing it to "none" fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and had to flush my DNS on my mac for it to clear up.